# upip installing in .frozen

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-zero

On a Raspberry Pi Zero W with MicroPython, installing libraries with upip says:

```
>>> import upip
>>> upip.debug = True
>>> upip.install('micropython-pystone')
Installing to: .frozen/
```

I want to instal to /lib/ instead of .frozen/. How do I tell it where to install a package? When I run the code it tells it can't import the modules I just installed. Removing the /lib/ folder from the Raspberry Pi Zero W and installing upip and the lib folder with it didn't work.

Comment: A rpi w zero is not a microcontroller, technically :) but that's mostly semantics for you as beginner. But I think you're confusing what micropython is and what modules in micropython are. Upip is just a library, micropython is your language runtime environment. Maybe making the difference now clear mentally makes it easier to understand what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem, solved it by running:

```
upip.install('micropython-pystone', '/lib')
```